# Eliminating any subset of quantifiers by Skolemization: no constants, please!

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

Can you use Skolemization to reduce a formula to the variables you want it to be about? I was trying to think of a nice algorithmic way to do it but only ended up having problems.

Say you have a formula $G$ in prenex normal form, i.e. something looking like this:

$$G \equiv Q_1x_1...Q_nx_n\;F$$

where $Q_i$ are quantifiers binding variables $x_i$ and occuring exclusively on the left of formula $F$ (which, consequently does not contain quantifiers itself). It is known that $G$ can be transformed into Skolem normal form, i. e. all existential quantifiers can be eliminated by substituting the variables they are binding by functions. But can *any* variable be substituted so that in the end the formula expresses something about the variables you wish to keep?

The possibly cheapest way to do it involves bracketing $F$ with its nearest quantifier.

*[EDIT: as you can read in the comments, this manoeuvre involves a major flaw, which shall stay undeleted for the record.]*

If the quantifier nearest to $F$ is $\exists$,  it would go like this:

$$Q_1x_1...Q_{n-1}x_{n-1}\;\exists x_n\;F$$
$$Q_1x_1...Q_{n-1}x_{n-1}\;(\exists x_n\;F)$$
$$Q_1x_1...Q_{n-1}x_{n-1}\;(F[x_n/c_1])$$

...where $F[x_n/c_1]$ expresses that $x_n$ has been substituted by constant $c_1$ in  $F$.

If the quantifier nearest to $F$ is $\forall$, the procedure takes some extra legwork and two negations:

$$Q_1x_1...Q_{n-1}x_{n-1}\;(\forall x_n F)$$
$$Q_1x_1...Q_{n-1}x_{n-1}\;(\neg \exists x_n\;\neg F)$$
$$Q_1x_1...Q_{n-1}x_{n-1}\;\neg (\exists x_n\;\neg F)$$
$$Q_1x_1...Q_{n-1}x_{n-1}\;(\neg F[x_n/c_1])$$

Iterating the process for all bound variables would leave you with a formula with no quantifiers but many constants you cannot assume much about.

To sustain "expessive power" regarding the variables designated to stay, there ought to be a way to substitute the rest of the variables by functions with arities higher than 0. I was thinking of (if required, repeatedly) putting the formula in the following form:

$$Q_1x_1...Q_{n-1}x_{n-1}\;(\forall y_{k} ... \forall y_n\;\exists x_n F)$$
$$Q_1x_1...Q_{n-1}x_{n-1}\;(\forall y_{k} ... \forall y_n\;F[x_n/f(y_{k},..., y_n)])$$

...where $y_i$ shall be the variables preserved in the final form and $x_i$ the variables to be eliminated.

Two problems arise:

1) As any quantifiers can bind $y_i$ in the original prenex normal form, the existential quantifiers binding $y_i$ must first be rephrased into universal ones for the Skolemization to yield functions of $y_i$. This does not always lead to a chain of universal quantifiers with no negations in between. It seems like it's not always possible to get rid of the negation in $\forall y_i \; \neg \forall y_{i-1}$.

2) Consequently, opportunities to rephrase $Q_ix_i\; Q_{i+1}x_{i+1}$ as $Q_{i+1}x_{i+1}\;Q_ix_i$ are limited.

So far, I managed to fabricate formulas containing only the variables I picked as survivors in the initial stage. Anyway, I could not avoid constants in every case. Can you think of a procedure with rules that would prevent constants appearing in any resulting formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your version of Skolemization is incorrect, and we can see this at the very first step. "$\forall xL(x)$" is **not** equivalent to "$\neg L(x/c)$:" while the former implies the latter, the latter doesn't imply the former (how do we know $c$ wasn't "chosen badly"?) Similarly, "$\exists x L(x)$" is not equivalent to "$L(x/c)$:" while the latter implies the former,the former doesn't imply the latter (for the same reason as above. So  the way you've introduced constants is broken.

Skolemization doesn't introduce new functions - rather, it introduces new *existential quantifiers over functions*. E.g. the Skolemized version of "$\forall x\exists yL(x, y)$" is "$\exists F^1\forall x(L(x, F(x)))$." (The "$^1$" indicates that $F$ is a *unary* function symbol.)

Things get clearer once we have more than one existential quantifier. The Skolemized version of "$\exists x\forall y\exists z L(x, y, z)$"  is "$\exists F^0\exists G^1\forall y(L(F^0, y, G(y)))$." Note two things here:

- All the existential function quantifiers are together, at the front.
- We've proceeded *from the outside in*: the $F^0$ corresponds to $x$, and the $G^1$ corresponds to $y$.

Basically, the Skolemized version of a formula "$\overline{Q}\overline{x}L(\overline{x})$" is "There are functions picking witnesses for the existential quantifiers in $\overline{Q}$ appropriately."

---

By the way, we can also perform "partial" Skolemization: we can Skolemize away any subset of the first-order existential quantifiers while leaving the rest. For instance, $$\forall x\exists y\forall z\exists w\forall a\exists b(L(x, y, z,w, a, b))$$ is equivalent to $$\exists F^1\exists G^2\exists H^3\forall x \forall z\forall a(L(x, F(x), z, G(x, z), a, H(x, z, a)))$$ (this is the fully Skolemized version), but it's also equivalent to the *partially* Skolemized sentence $$\exists F^1\exists H^3\forall x\forall z\exists w\forall a(L(x, F(x), z, w, a, H(x, z, a))).$$ *Note that when we leave an existential quantifier alone it stays where it was - it doesn't move to the front.*

Comment: Was reading this answer and I find it extremely clear. Only one point. How can it be that $\forall x L(x)$ implies $\neg L(x/c)$? This is not clear to me!

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstand you, this doesn't work.

Say you have $\forall x \exists y Loves(x,y)$ : Everyone loves someone.

By your method you get (again, if I understand you correctly):

$\forall x Loves(x,c_1)$

But that can't be right, for that would imply that there is something $c_1$ that everyone loves.  But if I have $a$ and $b$ (and not other objects in my domain) and $a$ loves $b$,  $b$ loves $a$, but $a$ and $b$ do not love themselves, then $\forall x \exists y Loves(x,y)$ is true but $\forall x Loves(x,c_1)$ is false: $c_1$ cannot be $a$, and also not be $b$, and there are no other objects.

This is exactly why you can only eliminate existentials by using a function that shows that the 'something' is dependent on the choice of objects for the universal quantifiers in front of it: if I pick $a$, I can point to $b$ as the something that $a$ loves, but if I pick $b$, I point to $a$.  So you have to think about this process 'outside-in', rather than 'inside-out'.

Comment: Nice, +1! While the one-quantifier step is already broken (see my answer), this drives the point home, and might be clearer to the OP.